# How do you show populated values in forms?

Tags: forms, prototype, mockup

I’m trying to improve the consistency in form designs (for tickets) while informing all members of the team (design/dev/product) of the type of answer that would make a specific input field ‘completed’. I would like you to think about how this would work in a summary page as well.

For example if the input field was ‘Account holder’s name’, **which would be a more efficient populated example?**

a) Mr John Salt
b) [Mr John Salt]

Ive been moving towards ‘b’ as I’d like to show that this is an example (even though 'a)' works as well). This potentially works better in a situation where the value may be a numerical value like a ‘[value]%’ or one of several options from a radio list like '[Yes/No].

Thanks
[image: Example of option b]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option A is the correct one.**

That's the idea of [**mockups**](https://www.lucidchart.com/blog/wireframes-vs-mockups), to test with similar content to the one you'll finally use. With **Option B**, by consistently adding punctuation signs, you're actually conveying *those fields will require that specific sign to be used*, which of course is wrong.

If everybody know it's a test, there are no additional requirements, just use placeholder text as intended

Answer (score 0):

Agreed - rather than showing a "variable" state for each field, it might be better to show multiple states of the form with different, properly representative content in each to show the different options (this is just a quick n dirty idea):

[image]

If there are different formats you want to try, do a couple of states in each format and A/B test them with your users to see which makes more sense them.